# How can I hide 0% value in data labels in an Excel Bar Chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I would like to hide data labels on a chart that have 0% as a value. I can get it working when the value is a number and not a percentage. I could delete the 0% but the data is going to change on a daily basis.

I am doing a if statement to calculate which column to put the data into.Data is shown below
[image]

I have 2 bars one green and one red. When the value is above 8% the red bar shows and when the value is below 8%. At one time i can only show one bar. I would like to hide the 0% as the bar isnt being show.

[image]

Comment: You must have two columns for the data to show like this.  In your source data, create a statement that if the result is zero to replace it with "#N/A"

Answer (score 13):

The quick and easy way to accomplish this is to custom format your data label.

1. Select a data label.
2. Right click and select Format Data Labels
3. Choose the Number category in the Format Data Labels dialog box.
4. Select Custom in the Category box.
5. In the format code box, enter `0%;-0%;` and click Add.
6. Close out of your dialog box and your 0% labels should be gone.

This works because Excel looks to your custom format to see how to format `Postive;Negative;0` values.  By leaving a blank after the final `;`, Excel formats any 0 value as a blank.

Comment: Note that this doesn't help if you want to have your labels also include Category/Series name in addition to the values (not the case for OP but I was looking to do this and it looks like I will not be able to).

Comment: @DanHenderson Yeah this is 7 years later, lol. If you need to optionally hide custom labels, you can use the Value from Cells option and refer to a column on the spreadsheet where you use formulas to construct the appropriate label which could be an empty string, etc.

Answer (score 3):

If using Office 2013 or later, type the format as mentioned above by Dav and Erik combined, i.e.

1. Select a data label.
2. Right click and select Format Data Labels
3. Choose the Number category in the Format Data Labels dialog box.
4. Select Custom in the Category box.
5. In the format code box, enter 0%;-0%; "" and click Add.
6. **After this, select the newly added format in the Type box.**
7. Close out of your dialog box and your 0% labels should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the `=NA()` value in your empty Cells.

Comment: The chart shows #N/A

Comment: I was thinking more for the data-values than the labels.